# Trying to output command-line arguments results in a seemingly random hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm at an intermediate level with C#, so for the learning experience, I'm attempting to learn C++ to a similar degree. Starting now as a complete beginner, I have attempted to loop through command-line arguments in an effort to familiarise myself with the syntax changes. Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

#include "CPP Sandbox.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "argc = " << argc << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        cout << argv[i] << "\n";
    }

}
```

I'm working in Visual Studio 2012, and attempting to run the program with the following arguments;

> test -p argc alnsot

set through Debug > CPP Sandbox Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Arguments.

I think it's clear what the application is intended to do, but instead of outputting the arguments, it outputs a seemingly random (changes every attempt) 4 byte hexadecimal string (the first byte and second bytes always equal, the third equals for the last four). A sample output would be:

> argc = 5
>
> 00CE89E8
>
> 00CE8A44
>
> 00CE8A49
>
> 00CE8A4C
>
> 00CE8A51

What am I doing wrong? Also, what is the first argument, which is always present but different on each run?
Forgive me if I am blind to an obvious mistake, but Google speaks of nothing.

Comment: Try Character Set "Not Set" in General options for your project.  If that works, convert the strings to char * instead of wchar_t * before outputting them.

Comment: @ebyrob That first suggestion fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Yes, cout (and stringstream) don't like Unicode much.  PS what ever happened to: `_tmain`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the code as written so it works with any compiler options:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "argc = " << argc << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        cout << (char*)argv[i] << endl;  // shows how broken main(_TCHAR) is

        char szTemp[1024] = {0};
        sprintf_s(szTemp, "%s", argv[i]); // works but... isn't wcstombs()
        cout << szTemp << "\n";

        // -or- much simpler:
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);    // printf seems to naturally handle _TCHAR*
    }
}
```

Over the long weekend I realized this is all wrong:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) // completely invalid TCHAR / char * mix
```

Valid choices are:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) // project options choose char type
int main(int argc, char **argv)      // always use char * for command line input
```

Here are four ways you can use the `TCHAR` setup:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    cout << "argc = " << argc << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        USES_CONVERSION;
        char *pszArg = T2A(argv[i]);  // ATL conversion macros
        cout << pszArg << endl;       // I recommend this unless no ATL at all.

        char szChar[1024] = {0};
        size_t useless;
        wcstombs_s(&useless, szChar, argv[i], 1024); // TCHAR is wchar_t only
        cout << szChar << endl; 

        wstring ws = argv[i];
        string s(ws.begin(), ws.end());  // C++ std::string TCHAR is wchar_t
        cout << s.c_str() << endl;

        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT); // _O_WTEXT _O_U16TEXT
        wcout << argv[i] << endl;        // C++ std::wcout kind of dicey...
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
}
```

Comment: Nice, forgive me if I ask what "%s\n" is for (and by extension, simply "%s")?

Comment: @Musiphonix sorry for slow response, `%s` is a printf format specifier for string.  `\n` is a newline C string constant.  For more about printf See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   //...
}
```

standard, than MSVC's `_TCHAR` that confuses me also all the time...

Comment: Yep, either don't use `_TCHAR` at all, or make sure you perform the proper conversions any time you specifically need `wchar_t` or `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use _tprintf to do what you're asking or make your own definition of something like tcout:

```
//tstream.h
#ifndef TSTREAM_H
#define TSTREAM_H 1

#include <iostream>
#ifdef _UNICODE
std::wostream& tcout = std::wcout;
#else
std::ostream& tcout = std::cout;
#endif

#endif //!TSTREAM_H
```

Naturally you can extend it for something like tcin and tclog in the same manner.

Comment: When is it `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);` becomes necessary with `wcout`?  Is that only to show non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `_TCHAR`, it will probably be simpler (and maybe make it work) to use a normal `char` instead.

To answer your second question, in C#, the `string[] args` is populated with ONLY the arguments passed to your program. In C/C++, `argv` is populated with the path to your compiled program and THEN the actual arguments.